# A better javascript to string function?

Tags: javascript, string

Before I go and create this myself, I thought I'd see if anyone knows a library that does this.

I'm looking for a function that will take something in Javascript, be it an array, an associative array, a number, or even a string, and convert it to something that looks like it.  For example:

```
toString([1,2,3]) === '[1, 2, 3]'
toString([[1,2], [2,4], [3,6]]) === '[[1,2], [2,4], [3,6]]'
toString(23) === '23'
toString('hello world') === 'hello world'
toString({'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}) === "{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}"
```

Comment: Mmm... `JSON.stringify` should come close I think

Comment: Basically you want to create JSON :) http://json.org/

Comment: Is the 'hello world' example correct or did you forget to add quotes? If this is the case then `JSON.stringify` is what you're searching for.

Comment: @Jeff: do you need any more help here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments (and I'm surprised nobody actually posted it as an answer), `JSON.stringify()` is the method that you're looking for.  It's supported natively in most browsers these days, but you can also implement it in the browsers that don't support it using [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/WXfzJ/**

The only exception is function objects, which won't be stringified by JSON.  However, `Function.prototype.toString` will return a re-parseable string representation of the function, although you should be aware that white-space and comments may be stripped depending on the browser:

```
function moo() {
    alert('cow says moo!');
}

alert(moo.toString());
```

Comment: Be wary of JSON.stringify("foo") === ""foo""

Comment: Mention the non-standard `.toString` on functions for printing out source code.

Comment: @Raynos: was just in the process of doing so :-) by the way, it *is* part of the spec, except that it is defined that the resulting source code can be implementation dependant.  This means, for user code, white-space and comments may be stripped.

Comment: @AndyE I swear IE just prints [object Function] or something for `.toString`

Comment: @Raynos: nope, that would be the result of `Object.prototype.toString.apply(fn)`.

Comment: @AndyE and @Raynos that will be returned for internal methods... methods defined via javascript will be returned as the string for an anonymous function representing the method in question, note: some browsers may adjust or optimize the function and remove whitespace/comments etc.

Comment: @Tracker: for internal methods, `toString()` usually looks something like `function functionName() { [native code] }`, although some browsers do differ on this (like BlackBerry's browser).